# Excel Formula - SUMIF / INDEX / MATCH

Tags: excel-formula

New here guys, first post.

Struggling with; 
- summing values from a range, where I wish to add all values in the range on months that fall between certain dates.

E.g. in cell B9, I want to add all values from range B6:R6 which are ">=" B1 & "<" B2. The answer for this will be sum(B6:K6). Alas, I cannot quite get there.

You will see my attempt as;
**=SUMIFS(INDEX($B$6:$R$6,,MATCH(AND(">=" & B1, "<" & B2),$B$4:$R$4,0),0),$B$4:$R$4,">=" & B1,$B$4:$R$4,"<" & B2)**

[Excel extract](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIXZp.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need the INDEX:

```
=SUMIFS(6:6,4:4,">=" & B1,4:4,"<=" & B2)
```

Comment: Wow that seems so simple. You're good. Much appreciated it's exactly it !